# Angular2, HTTP post, send dynamic json

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I need to get postKey and postValue from other function that will send
the key name and key value, and then post it.
but I cannot find a way to send stringify vars and not static value

like this it is not working:

```js
  postRequest(postKey?: any, postValue? any){
    return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({postKey: PostValue } ))
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

only like this is working (static):

```js
  postRequest(post?: any){
        return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({SomeKey: 'SomeValue' } ))
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achievable via using [`ES6` feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
postRequest(postKey?: any, postValue){
   return this._http.post(this._url, postKey ? JSON.stringify({[postKey]: PostValue }: null ))
      .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: I am getting errors:
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | number)[]'.
  Property 'find' is missing in type '{}'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\shay\Desktop\Angular2\cloud\src\app\http_request.service.ts:54:91
':' expected.

Comment: @ShayBinyat try `null` instead of `{}`

Comment: still not ok - it wants "," before the null          ERROR in [default] C:\Users\shay\Desktop\Angular2\cloud\src\app\http_request.service.ts:57:104
',' expected.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\shay\Desktop\Angular2\cloud\src\app\http_request.service.ts:57:112
':' expected.

Answer (score 0):

solved it like this:

```js
 return this._http.post(this._url, '{"' + postKey + '": "' + postValue + '"}')
```